# Ms access database is automatically started to store data from 1st row again

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2007

I am using vb6 to store data in database. It want working fine until 150 records(row in database) but after that the data is getting store from first row  and even if i sort it in the ascending order it does not get sorted in datagrid and because of this i am having problem for fetching the ordernumber for my next order in menu form(its about my vb6 project).

```
Private Sub CmdDone_Click()
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, Y, z, aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj, kk As Integer
Dim ll, mm, nn, oo, pp, qq, rr, ss As Integer
Dim flag As Integer
flag = 0
Set db = OpenDatabase("D:\OrderMania\ordermania.mdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from order1")
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs.MoveLast
GoTo 1
End If
1 If StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Enter Your Name"), vbExclamation
    TxtName.SetFocus
    flag = 1
End If
If ComboTable.Text = "Select" Then
       MsgBox ("Please Select The Table Number"), vbExclamation
       ComboTable.SetFocus
       flag = 1
 Else
        If Check1.Value = 1 Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(7).Value = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
        rs.Fields(0).Value = TextOrNO.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = ComboTable.Text
        rs.Fields(6).Value = TxtDate.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = UserControl1.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = Check1.Caption
        rs.Fields(4).Value = "20"
        rs.Fields(5).Value = UserControl1.Text * 20
        a = UserControl1.Text * 20
        rs.Fields(8).Value = "Pending"
        rs.Fields(9).Value = "Waiting"
        rs.Update
        End If

        If Check2.Value = 1 Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(7).Value = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
        rs.Fields(0).Value = TextOrNO.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = ComboTable.Text
        rs.Fields(6).Value = TxtDate.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = UserControl2.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = Check2.Caption
        rs.Fields(4).Value = "15"
        rs.Fields(5).Value = UserControl2.Text * 15
        b = UserControl2.Text * 15
        rs.Fields(8).Value = "Pending"
        rs.Fields(9).Value = "Waiting"
        rs.Update

        End If

        If Check3.Value = 1 Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(7).Value = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
        rs.Fields(0).Value = TextOrNO.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = ComboTable.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = UserControl3.Text
        rs.Fields(6).Value = TxtDate.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = Check3.Caption
        rs.Fields(4).Value = "12"
        rs.Fields(5).Value = UserControl3.Text * 12
        c = UserControl3.Text * 12
        rs.Fields(8).Value = "Pending"
        rs.Fields(9).Value = "Waiting"
        rs.Update

        End If

        If Check4.Value = 1 Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(7).Value = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
        rs.Fields(0).Value = TextOrNO.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = ComboTable.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = UserControl4.Text
        rs.Fields(6).Value = TxtDate.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = Check4.Caption
        rs.Fields(4).Value = "20"
        rs.Fields(5).Value = UserControl4.Text * 20
        d = UserControl4.Text * 20
        rs.Fields(8).Value = "Pending"
        rs.Fields(9).Value = "Waiting"
        rs.Update

        End If

        If Check5.Value = 1 Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(7).Value = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
        rs.Fields(0).Value = TextOrNO.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = ComboTable.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = UserControl5.Text
        rs.Fields(6).Value = TxtDate.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = Check5.Caption
        rs.Fields(4).Value = "20"
        rs.Fields(5).Value = UserControl5.Text * 20
        e = UserControl5.Text * 20
        rs.Fields(8).Value = "Pending"
        rs.Fields(9).Value = "Waiting"
        rs.Update

        End If
End If
TxtTotal.Text = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + Y + z + aa + bb + cc + dd + ee + ff + gg + hh + ii + jj + kk + ll + mm + nn + oo + pp + qq + rr + ss
Tot = CInt(TxtTotal.Text)
If flag = 0 Then
MsgBox "Your Order has been Placed", vbOKOnly, "Done"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdBill_Click()
Dim Tot As Integer
Dim gst, gtot As Double
Tot = 0
Set db = OpenDatabase("D:\OrderMania\ordermania.mdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from order1")


While Not rs.EOF
  If StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase) = rs.Fields(7).Value And TextOrNO.Text = rs.Fields(0).Value Then

      Form7.List1.AddItem (rs.Fields(2).Value)
      Form7.List2.AddItem (rs.Fields(4).Value)
      Form7.List3.AddItem (rs.Fields(3).Value)
      Form7.List4.AddItem (rs.Fields(5).Value)
      Form7.Text2.Text = rs.Fields(1).Value
      Form7.Text7.Text = rs.Fields(6).Value
      Tot = Tot + rs.Fields(5).Value
    End If
rs.MoveNext
Wend
Form7.Text6.Text = Tot
gst = Tot * 0.05
Form7.Text5.Text = gst
gtot = Tot + gst
Form7.Text4.Text = gtot
Form7.Text3.Text = StrConv(TxtName.Text, vbProperCase)
Form7.Text1.Text = TextOrNO.Text
Form7.Show
Unload Me

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Activate()
TxtName.SetFocus
End Sub
Private Sub generateOID()
Dim db1 As Database
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Set db1 = OpenDatabase("D:\OrderMania\ordermania.mdb")
Set rs1 = db1.OpenRecordset("select * from order1")
If rs1.EOF = True Then
TextOrNO.Text = 1
Exit Sub
Else
rs1.MoveLast
TextOrNO.Text = rs1.Fields(0).Value + 1
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()

Call generateOID
TxtName.Text = ""
ComboTable.Text = "Select"
TxtDate.Text = Date
lblTime.Caption = Time
TextOrNO.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `TextOrNO.Text` as your Order Number but you are not increasing that value after the order is placed.

In `generateOID`, modify the `SELECT` statement to sort the data:

```
Private Sub generateOID()
    Dim db1 As Database
    Dim rs1 As Recordset

    Set db1 = OpenDatabase("D:\OrderMania\ordermania.mdb")
    Set rs1 = db1.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM order1 ORDER BY odrno ASC")

    If rs1.EOF = True Then
        TextOrNO.Text = 1
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rs1.MoveLast
        TextOrNO.Text = rs1.Fields(0).Value + 1
    End If

End Sub
```